# local date being saved as utcin est zone - MariaDB

Tags: java, mariadb, localdate

I have an expiration date, that's declared as LocalDate in java. While saving in MariaDB its being saved as UTC, ie 5.5 hrs being deducted from the original time.
So when Im saving expiration date as '10-05-2018' , it is being saved in database as '10-04-2018'. While retrieving Im getting the correct date, ie '10-05-2018'.

How do I make sure its being saved as the same date in database as well?

Update : Its weird, its showing different date in my machines database, but showing the right date in a different machine database.

Comment: How did you declare the date column? I suspect you didn't declare the date to be in a specific timezone so it'll use the server's default timezone.

Comment: How do you export the data from the database to the java application, json rest, hibernate or others?

Comment: Aren’t you using the [`date`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/date/) datatype in MariaDB? It doesn’t have time of day, so there is no way of subtracting 5.5 hours.

Comment: @Thomas : Yes we didnt delcare it to be in specific timezone. Its deployed in cloud. I suspect its taking whatever the zone its deployed in. Do I need to specify the timezone, which would be usually EST, but sometimes it can be used from PST too

Comment: @E : we are using JPA, hibdernate

Comment: Well, Java dates internally are defined in utc anyways and any timezone specific conversions would only be done when parsing a string or formatting the date to a string. Databases should do the same so when you read the date as string in some database manager you'll probably get it formatted for UTC. The column definition would probably only matter if you'd enter the date as a string in which case it would either expect the string to contain timezone information or just use the default timezone to interpret the string.

Comment: @OleV.V. : we are using date datatype only. But somehow its subtracting 5.5 hrs!!!

Comment: its wierd, its showing different date in my machines database, but showing the right date in a different machine database.

Comment: Study the difference between `TIMESTAMP` and `DATATIME` datatypes.

Comment: What are your system timezone settings?

Comment: @RickJames : All are set to EST

Comment: `EST` is not a real time zone. Time zones have names in `Continent/Region` format. See [this list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).

Answer (score 3):

## tl;dr

Using `DATE` in SQL, and `LocalDate` in Java, means never having a problem of five and a half hours.

## `DATE` data type

To store a date-only value, without time-of-day and without time zone or offset, in your database, use a date-only data type for your column.

In both the SQL standard and MariaDB, that would be [`DATE`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/date/).

With JDBC 4.2 and later you can directly exchange *java.time* objects such as `LocalDate` with the database.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 2018 , Month.JANUARY , 23 ) ;
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , ld ) ;
```

And retrieval.

```
LocalDate ld = myResultSet.getObject( … , LocalDate.class ) ;
```

## Example app

When debugging such a problem, set your real app code aside and make a little demo app such as this, to simplify the problem and eliminate various contributing factors.

Here is a simple but complete example app.

This example uses the [H2 Database Engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H2_(DBMS)), built in Java, for simplicity. Adapt this code to your particular database server to make a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

```
package com.basilbourque.example;

import java.sql.*;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.Month;

public class DateTest {
    public static void main ( String[] args ) {
        DateTest app = new DateTest();
        app.doIt();
    }

    private void doIt ( ) {
        try {
            Class.forName( "org.h2.Driver" );
        } catch ( ClassNotFoundException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try (
                Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection( "jdbc:h2:mem:example_db;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1" ) ; // Set `DB_CLOSE_DELAY` to `-1` to keep in-memory database in existence after connection closes.
                Statement stmt = conn.createStatement() ;
        ) {
            // Create table.
            String sql = "CREATE TABLE event_ (\n" +
                    "  pkey_ IDENTITY NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY ,\n" +
                    "  name_ VARCHAR NOT NULL ,\n" +
                    "  when_ DATE NOT NULL\n" +
                    ") ; ";
            System.out.println( sql );
            stmt.execute( sql );

            // Insert row.
            sql = "INSERT INTO event_ ( name_ , when_ ) " + "VALUES ( ? , ? ) ;";
            try ( PreparedStatement preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement( sql ) ; ) {
                String name = "whatever";
                LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 2018 , Month.JANUARY , 23 ) ;

                preparedStatement.setString( 1 , name );
                preparedStatement.setObject( 2 , ld );
                preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
            }

            // Query all.
            sql = "SELECT * FROM event_ ;";
            try ( ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery( sql ) ; ) {
                while ( rs.next() ) {
                    //Retrieve by column name
                    Long pkey = rs.getLong( "pkey_" );
                    String name = rs.getString( "name_" );
                    LocalDate ld = rs.getObject( "when_" , LocalDate.class );

                    //Display values
                    System.out.println( "pkey: " + pkey + " | name: " + name + " | when: " + ld );
                }
            }
        } catch ( SQLException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

When run.

> pkey: 1 | name: whatever | when: 2018-01-23